# accessing JSON through javascript in ejs file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ejs

Hello I would like to get any help to get through this issue with my code.

so this is my server file with node js

```
//setup

var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

//make body-parser workin
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//help excluding ejs extension
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
//pointing express to look at public folders for css files. 
app.use(express.static("public"));


//routing starts
//root directory
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render("home", { data : "" });
});

app.post("/results", function(req, res){
    var mname = req.body.movieName;
    var myear = req.body.movieYear;
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s="+mname+"&y="+myear+"&apikey=$$$$$$$$$$$$";
    request(url, function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
       var data = JSON.parse(body);
       res.render("home", { data : data });
       console.log(url);
    }else{
      console.log("ERRRORRRR WARNNNINNNNNNGG");
      console.log(error);
    }

    });
```

and this is part of my ejs file that want to access the JSON retrieved from API request

```
<%= data["Search"][0] %>
```

However, I get error like this

====================================================================
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/MovieSearchApp/views/home.ejs:32

> > 32|  <%= data["Search"][0] %>

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at eval (eval at compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/MovieSearchApp node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:549:12), <anonymous>:11:40) 

etc
```

====================================================================

so I am assuming my way to access the JSON is somehow wrong so I looked at my JSON in detail
[image: json example]

and I went back to my ejs file and tried

```
<%= data["Search"] %>
```

it gives me no error and shows up as

```
[object Object]
```

could somebody give me some direction to how to access this JSON correctly?

thanks for your time and help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious issue is that you are passing `data: ""` in `app.get("/",..`

This means that when you go to your website's root `/` the `data` is a empty string.

Change it to

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
   res.render("home");
});
```

and in the view check if data exists

```
<% if (data) { %>

<% } else { %>

<% } %>
```

Comment: Hello Molda! when I removed the {data : "" } from get request, it gives me error as "data is not defined". So I tried to add that part again try to console.log(data) out (within the POST request after JSON.parse(body) line) and I can see JSON on my terminal windows. So it looks like the data is well retrieved from the API request however I am not sure how to properly access to it.

Comment: The thing is that you set data to `""` in get request and then you're trying to access `data['Search'][0]` but `data['Search']`  is `undefined`.  It is understandable that it works in app.post since you're retrieving the data from omdbapi.com. You are not doing that in get request though. You could change `res.render("home");` to `res.render("home", { data: { Search: [] } });` but even this won't work because `data['Search'][0]` will be undefined. You shouldn't try to access variables you are not sure exist.

Comment: Oh!!!!!  I can see it now.  I am going to try to separate the post request in different ejs file and let you know in minutes!!!!!!

Comment: Cool, glad i could help